# SSRS - Major/minor gridlines spacing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I have an SSRS report with a bar chart with multiple series by CountryName Category group.  What I want to do is have gridlines which split each country like below:

[image]

However in SSRS the major gridlines seem to interval with the line in the middle of the country name when the grid interval is set to 1 like below:

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction into how to rectify this?

Also is there a way of adding the X axis in SSRS to start from zero like I have in my first graph?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, there is an offset property on the grid lines (horizontal and vertical are separate). Click one one of the gridlines and look in the properties pane. Change the offset to 0.5.

[image: Gridline properties]

Gives you this.
[image: Gridline offset = 0.5]

I'm not sure what you meant about starting from zero on the X-Axis, you have negative values so you'll start from a negative number. If you meant you wantde zero aligned to the middle. You can do that to. You need to set the min and max values of the horizontal axis to the following

Min Value:

```
=MAX(ABS(Fields!MyValueField.Value), "MyDataSet")*-1
```

Max Value will be:

```
=MAX(ABS(Fields!MyValueField.Value), "MyDataSet")
```

Basically we take the ABSolute largest value and use that as the extent (*-1 for the min value). The problem is that zero might not show so you'll have to play around with the Axis properties maybe to get that working. I'm sure it's possible but I don't have time to test at the moment.

My test data is not great as the number are large

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.  With regards the line through zero in the x axis I've added a strip line in the chart axis appearance property.  Thanks for your help.